# Material ui InputBase can not be hided by other elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

As shown below, the first row is a **sticky** nav, and rows after are all `InputBase` component in material-ui. Though I already set the background color of the nav bar to white, the `input` always gets showed up above the nav. And this peculiar behavior disappeared after I changed `InputBase` to my custom `div`.

Here is a live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-k2g5l

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something odd was going on with the z-index. In addition, your sticky nav wasn't full width.

I added zIndex: 9999 and also 100% width.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-n87zv

Here's the revision:

```
import React from "react";
import { createStyles, makeStyles, Theme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import { InputBase } from "@material-ui/core";
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      "& > *": {
        margin: theme.spacing(1),
        width: "25ch"
      }
    },
    main: {
      overflowX: "auto",
      height: "100px",
      width: "100px"
    },
    nav: {
      position: "sticky",
      top: 0,
      backgroundColor: "white",
      zIndex: 9999,
      width: "100%"
    },
    rows: {
      display: "flex",
      flexDirection: "column",
      flexWrap: "nowrap"
    }
  })
);

export default function BasicTextFields() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.main}>
      <div className={classes.nav}>NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN</div>
      <div className={classes.rows}>
        <InputBase placeholder="xxxxxx" />
        <InputBase placeholder="xxxxxx" />
        <InputBase placeholder="xxxxxx" />
        <InputBase placeholder="xxxxxx" />
        <InputBase placeholder="xxxxxx" />
        <InputBase placeholder="xxxxxx" />
        <InputBase placeholder="xxxxxx" />
        <InputBase placeholder="xxxxxx" />
        <InputBase placeholder="xxxxxx" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: so what‘s really going on？I cheked in chrome dev mode and didn’t find anything related to z-index

Comment: @BAKEZQ - not sure lol. I also just tried checking again and I didn't see the Z-Index show up in Chrome dev tools this time. However, what piqued my interest the first time was catching that the Z-Index was "1" on some element.

Comment: I also tried to set this z-index to 0 and set 1 to nav, and it didn't work. Learned that I should try a higher z-index next time.

Comment: I just did 9999 as I've seen it done that way quite a few times in my web dev career. It's just a lazy way of setting it :)